# How to update files in auto scaled elastic beanstalk instances

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, autoscaling

I have launched an Elastic beanstalk instance in AWS with default sample php application. And I created new index.html file in /var/www/html. I have enabled auto scaling in my elastic beanstalk configuration. When I create elastic beanstalk, instance 'A' launched, when threshold exceed the limit another instance 'B' launched. Then when I refresh my website, the index.php (default) executing, and another refresh index.html(created myself) executing.

From where instance 'B' getting the data. And how should I make changes in my website to reflect on every instances.

Comment: Why not AWS CodeDeploy: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/auto-scaling-integ.html

Answer (score 0):

Elastic Beanstalk is a combination of EC2 autoscaling and codedeploy.

You shouldn't manually create or edit anything on the elastic beanstalk EC2 instances, instead you should use the [eb configuration options](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers.html).

Creating the configuration along side your code allows you to deploy it using either the CLI (and git) or wrap it up in a zip file and upload it using the AWS console.

I wrote a [blog post](http://clarkie.io/devops/2015/11/10/configuring-aws-elastic-beanstalk-application.html) about some of the configuration options available.